# How to resolve org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, alert, webdriverwait

I used this code in Selenium Androiddriver

```
WebDriverWait waiter = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
Alert alert = waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

but I get the error message below.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented
```

What method is available to accomplish this?

Comment: Your question title states that the method is deprecated but the error message you posted states that it hasn't been implemented. Please edit your question and clarify. When you are editing your question, please also add a tag for the programming language you are using... Java?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented
```

...implies that a *WebDriverException* was raised when you tried to assign the return type from *ExpectedConditions* method `alertIsPresent()` to an instance of *Alert*.

The *ExpectedConditions* method [**`alertIsPresent()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#alertIsPresent--) when used in conjunction with *WebDriverWait* waits for the *alert to be present* and switches to the *Alert* once the *Alert* is present and you can directly invoke either `accept()` or `dismiss()` as follows :

- [**`accept()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#accept--) :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).accept();
  ```
- [**`dismiss()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#dismiss--) :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).dismiss();
  ```

**Note** : You need to add the following imports :

- `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;`
- `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;`
- `import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;`

Comment: i  getting same error(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented) after using new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).accept();                                                      configarations: android client--->java-client-5.0.4.jar, selenium version-->3.8.1.jar

Comment: @hari Checkout my answer update and consider upgrading to _Selenium client v3.12.0_